# XSLT 2.0: Copy and modify branch, but keep source in original state

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to copy a part of an XML document into a new element while making adjustments. However, I want to keep the source in its original state, the changes should only appear in the copy. Also, all other parts of the document have to be preserved.

Here is an example that tries to achieve the above while changing the contents of all elements with the attribute change="true" into upper-case.

**XML input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <original>
    <element change="true">abc</element>
    <element change="false">def</element>
  </original>
  <copy/>
  <other>preserve this</other>
</root>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/copy">
    <copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="/root/original/*"/>
    </copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/original/element[@change='true']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <original>
    <element change="true">ABC</element>
    <element change="false">def</element>
  </original>
  <copy>
    <element change="true">abc</element>
    <element change="false">def</element>
  </copy>
  <other>preserve this</other>
</root>
```

However, my current XSLT basically does the opposite of what I want, it changes only the original element to upper-case while duplicating the lower-case version to the "copy" branch.

**Desired output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <original>
    <element change="true">abc</element>
    <element change="false">def</element>
  </original>
  <copy>
    <element change="true">ABC</element>
    <element change="false">def</element>
  </copy>
  <other>preserve this</other>
</root>
```

I made a few tests with xsl:call-template but wasn't able to produce anything close to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `copy` to contain the changed output, you should be using `xsl:apply-templates` in the template, rather than `xsl:copy-of`. And to make sure `original` is unchanged, you will need a separate template that does `xsl:copy-of`.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/copy">
    <copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/original/*"/>
    </copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/original">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/original/element[@change='true']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Final Code
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/copy">
    <copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/original/*"/>
</copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/original">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/original/element[@change='true']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(.)"/>   
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think adding this template alone won't solve the issue, as there is still the issue with the `copy` node not getting changed to upper case.